# Extract new lines from log file to MYSQL

Tags: mysql

everyone.

I am new here, I was recommended by Onare, welp, this will be my first question.

I have a file for ex. "file.log" that contains printing logs.

> **LINE1:** PRINTERNAME | userwhichprinted | ID | DATE | 1 | 1 | - | FROMIP | FILENAME | - | -
>
> **LINE2:** PRINTERNAME | userwhichprinted | ID | DATE | 1 | 1 | - | FROMIP | FILENAME | - | -
>
> **LINE3:** PRINTERNAME | userwhichprinted | ID | DATE | 1 | 1 | - | FROMIP | FILENAME | - | -

And so on, actually it is a CUPS Server, someone may be familiarized with it.

I want to make a trigger that put every new line to the database. If there are any more questions needed, let me know, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like the following is what you are looking for?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/raw/data/file.log'
INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
;
```

Comment: I did try what you said, however, it doesn't import the file because it doesn't have permissions, I tried changing permissions to 711, 755, 777, X R, and none of them did work, though it gave a different error when I used 711.